# Sql Distinct Count of Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a query on a mysql database. I have a main table where users are stored and another table where friends of that user are stored.  For each user I want to see how many 
friends they have.  This is what I'm getting.

```
ID    FirstName LastName FriendID
1     Andrew    Smith     1
1     Andrew    Smith     5
1     Andrew    Smith     9
2     John      Doe       3
2     John      Doe       5
```

This is what I want to get.

```
ID    FirstName LastName Friends
1     Andrew    Smith     3
2     John      Doe       2
```

If this is not enough detail to go on let me know and I will also show the tables and query I used.

Comment: Is it right that John Doe (ID 2) maps to the same FriendID (3) twice and count as 2 friends?

Comment: Oh you're right, updated. I was trying to do the count without using the group by clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, COUNT(FriendID) AS Friends
    FROM Users GROUP BY ID, FirstName, LastName
```

One hopes you're not *really* storing FirstName and LastName in every UserFriendLink record.  If you are, it's time to normalize your database with a Users table (with ID, First, and Last) and a UserFriendsLink table (with UserID and FriendID).

Comment: In this example we can assume that users have lots of info associated with them. And that friends will never be users. My actual application is a bulletin board where there are posts and post replies. <br />for every post there can be multiple replies, replies have less fields associated with them and a reply will never be a post. but the example I gave above illustrates that relationship

Comment: The table I showed above was the result of my left join query which joined a few normalised tables

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was the group by that I was missing